# How to block the code generation when open DataContext designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, linq-to-sql

When I open the DataContextDesigner of LinqToSql for view or add/update Table and Filed the VS_2013 recreate all code of entities and I lose my modified in DataContext code.

It's possible block this behavior ?

Comment: Dont add your code to the `.Designer.cs` file. Another one is created for you specifically for this.

Comment: I remove the empty file .Designer.cs but when I open DataContext.dbml VS_STUDIO recreate all mapping and I lose my modified.